# How to split a CSV column with repeated text into split 0-1 columns for each possible text variant?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV with a column like

```
LABEL
a
b
a
a
c
n o
ye s
```

I want to split it into something like:

```
LABEL_a LABEL_b LABEL_c LABEL_n_o LABEL_ye_s
   1       0       0         0        0
   0       1       0         0        0
   1       0       0         0        0
   1       0       0         0        0
   0       0       1         0        0
   0       0       0         1        0
   0       0       0         0        1
```

How to do such thing with pandas?

Comment: Can you explain the logic for a 0 vs 1?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `pd.get_dummmies` with parameter `prefix`:

```
#Using @Lambda setup
label = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "n o", "ye s"]
s = pd.Series(label)

pd.get_dummies(s, prefix='label')
```

Output:

```
   label_a  label_b  label_c  label_n o  label_ye s
0        1        0        0          0           0
1        0        1        0          0           0
2        1        0        0          0           0
3        1        0        0          0           0
4        0        0        1          0           0
5        0        0        0          1           0
6        0        0        0          0           1
```

### Timings:

#### for keys loop method

```
> %%timeit for key in keys:
>     df[("label_%s" % key).replace(" ", "_")] = (s == key).astype(int)
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 6.7 ms per loop

#### String accessor get_dummies method

```
> %timeit s.str.get_dummies().add_prefix('label_')
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 6.03 ms per loop

#### pd.get_dummies with prefix parameter:

```
> %timeit pd.get_dummies(s, prefix='label')
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 ms per loop

Answer (score 3):

Using `get_dummies`

```
s.str.get_dummies().add_prefix('label_')
Out[19]: 
   label_a  label_b  label_c  label_n o  label_ye s
0        1        0        0          0           0
1        0        1        0          0           0
2        1        0        0          0           0
3        1        0        0          0           0
4        0        0        1          0           0
5        0        0        0          1           0
6        0        0        0          0           1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

label = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "n o", "ye s"]
s = pd.Series(label)
keys = s.unique()

df = pd.DataFrame()
for key in keys:
    df[("label_%s" % key).replace(" ", "_")] = (s == key).astype(int)
```

Comment: You should forbidden for loop when you with pandas

Comment: I think you are right, and I learn much from your answer, thanks.